# Sequential order of Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I'm having a bit of a problem with Javascript. I have a list of article titles which, when you click a title, the corresponding article appears on the right hand side (fixed at the top of the page). I have got these articles to fade in/out using Javascript. I also have a function which, when you are scrolled down and click on an article title, scrolls the page slowly back up to the top.

The problem I have is that when the page scrolls up and the article changes at the same time, the animations on both become quite choppy, especially in Safari. Is there any way to make the page scroll to the top first, then make the article change?

I'm basically asking if there is away to make my Javascript functions happen one after the other, rather than at the same time?

Heres my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.scrollup').click(function () {
      $("body").animate({
         scrollTop: 0
      }, 'slow');
      return false;
   });
   $('.articlelist ul li').click(function() {
      var i = $(this).index();
      $('.fullarticle').fadeTo(500,0);
      $('#article' + (i+1)).fadeTo(500,1);
   });
});
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Use the callback functions to run them one after the other. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and look at the `complete` function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to keep the click functionality on your article list and only the elements with class scrollup have 2 animations.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.articlelist ul li').click(function () {
        var i = $(this).index();
        if ($(this).is(".scrollup")) {
            $("body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 'slow', function () {//when animation completes
                fadeArticle(i);
            });
        } else {
            fadeArticle(i);
        }

    });

    function fadeArticle(i) {
        $('.fullarticle').fadeTo(500, 0);
        $('#article' + (i + 1)).fadeTo(500, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of html of the article list?

Comment: <div class="articlelist">
        <ul>
            <li onclick="toggleArticles('article1')" class="scrollup"><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
            <li onclick="toggleArticles('article2')" class="scrollup"><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>
            <li onclick="toggleArticles('article3')" class="scrollup"><a href="#">Article 3</a></li> </ul>

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `animate()` you'd want to add a function to be called upon completion. The animate function provided by JQuery takes a function as an optional parameter. When the animation completes that function is called.

You could use something like this:

```
$('.scrollup').click(function () {
    $("body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 'slow', showArticle);
    return false;
});
```

`showArticle` would be a call to a function that fades the article in like the anonymous one in your click listener. You would probably need some way to pass an argument about which article should be shown.

Comment: it should be `showArticle`, else you'll call that function immediately

Comment: Thanks, I always make that mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how to link the two functions together?

Comment: @user2798841 I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I've edited my answer to provide a bit more explanation of the `animate` functions callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to this, but I think this may work.  What I'm trying to do is enclose each of these as a callable function and then pass one function as the callback to the other.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
scrollTop(showArticle());
});


function scrollTop(callback) {
    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $("body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
        callback;
    });
}

function showArticle() {
    $('.articlelist ul li').click(function () {
        var i = $(this).index();
        $('.fullarticle').fadeTo(500, 0);
        $('#article' + (i + 1)).fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: both functions still seem to occur at the same time

Comment: I don't believe this code does anything terribly different from the example posted in the question. It adds two click listeners on document ready, but the first listener uses a callback to add the second listener.

Comment: Yeah you're right Blake the call to fade the article needs to be the callback on animate.  @Wilmer answer looks solid.